# From a shell script, execute another one with arguments and obtain its return code

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

On a i686 / 32-bit dual CPU, with a fresh Debian Stretch installation, I've installed Octave 4.2.1 and run `./mytest` after providing it with execution privileges:

```
#!/bin/bash
./mytest.m
```

where `test.m` reads

```
#!/usr/bin/octave
exit(0)
```

Given the two scripts stored in `~/tmp`, `mytest`

```
#!/bin/bash

if $1/mytest.m "$2"; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

and `mytest.m`

```
#!/usr/bin/octave

param = argv(){1};

if strcmp(param, "happyend")
  exit(0)
else
  exit(1)
end
```

Running `tmp/mytest tmp happyend` will pass `happyend` normally to `mytest` and subsequently to `mytest.m`, that will pass signal 0 back to `mytest`, that will print 'good'. Now, how to obtain the return (exit) code from `mytest.m` in a variable? (0 in the example above).

The intuitive option

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$("$1"/mytest.m "$2")

if [ $result = 0 ]; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the return (exit) code from a command, you need to save the `$?` value, perhaps into a variable called `result`:

```
"$1/mytest.m" "$2"
result=$?
if [ "$result" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

If you only want to save the result long enough to test it, skip the `result` variable with:

```
"$1/mytest.m" "$2"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

but be careful to immediately test `$?` after running mytest.m, as any subsequent commands will put *their* return code into `$?`.

If you only want to test whether the result is zero, you don't need to treat it as an integer. Just treat the command itself as a conditional.

```
if "$1/mytest.m" "$2"; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to directly assign the exit code to the variable? `result=something`

Comment: result=$?    assigns it directly

Comment: By 'direct' I meant something like `result=$("$1/mytest.m" "$2")`

Comment: the `$( ...)` syntax captures the stdout (output) from running the contents of the parenthesis, which is separate from the return code of the contents, so: no.

Comment: that was the whole point of the question. title updated accordingly.